# Running SQL query, returning response objects as array. I need to know how to create loop to read each record returned

Tags: javascript, arrays, karate

I am running a SQL query and returning objects as array in karate.  I 
know how to read the first record/row returned.  I need to know how to 
create a loop to read all the records, one at a time.

Here's the start where the SQL query is called and I am assigning objects 
to variables.

```
Scenario Outline: Premium-IC or IR Invoice Type  
* def op_ic_ir_query = karate.readAsString('classpath:Payments/
CSC_Payments_API/Queries/qry_Get_Overpayment_IC_IR.txt')
* def OP1 = Stardb.readRows(op_ic_ir_query)
* def OP_cpid = OP1[0].CONTRACT_PAYMENT_ID
* def OP_cid = OP1[0].CONTRACT_ID
* def OP_iid = OP1[0].INVOICE_ID
* def OP_Idate = OP1[0].INVOICE_DATE
* def OP_dtp = OP1[0].DATE_TO_PROCESS
* def transactionAmt = OP1[0].TRANSACTION_AMOUNT
* def invoiceAmt = OP1[0].INVOICE_AMOUNT
* def taxAmt = OP1[0].TAX_AMOUNT
* def paidAmt = OP1[0].PAID_AMOUNT
```

The next step is calculating an overpayment amount.

```
# Calculate overpayment_amount - need to keep rolling total for 
overpayment amount.
* def overpaymentAmt1 = (transactionAmt - ((invoiceAmt + taxAmt) - 
paidAmt))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the ways to do loops in Karate:

1) [`Scenario Outline` and `Examples`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-cucumber-way)

2) [Using `call` and a second feature file](https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features)

3) [Using JS](https://github.com/intuit/karate#loops)

Depending on what you want to do, maybe you should the loop in Java code itself, if it simplifies things.

My recommendation would be (2) since you have a dynamic array you need to loop over. So if `foo` is an array of JSON-s:

```
* def result = call read('second.feature') foo
```